# How to write JUnit testcase for a Class

Tags: java, junit

I am a fresher and I need to know how to write **JUnit** test cases for this class. Can anyone help me out?

```
package com.jpmc.cb.creos.util.grid;

public class GridHelper {

    public static List<GridFilter> getGridFilters(String jsonFilters)throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        List<GridFilter> filters = new ArrayList<GridFilter>();
        GridFilter filter[] = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFilters,
                GridFilter[].class);
        for (int i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
            filters.add(filter[i]);
        }
        return filters;
    }
}
```

---

This is the GridFilter Class:

```
package com.jpmc.cb.creos.util.grid;

public class GridFilter {

private String property;
private String value;
private String operator;

public GridFilter() {}

public GridFilter(String property, String operator, String value)
{
    this.property = property;
    this.value = value;
    this.operator = operator;
}

public String getProperty() {
    return property;
}

public void setProperty(String property) {
    this.property = property;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getOperator() {
    return operator;
}

public void setOperator(String operator) {
    this.operator = operator;
}

}
```

Comment: Which class? You mean the method?

Comment: GridHelper is the Class

Comment: You want to write a Unittest for method getGridFilters() ?

Comment: your question is really unclear, on one hand you are provideing a static method, and asking for help on writting a test for a class. Now you do provide the class only the code provided shows no refernce. Is your question regarding how to test static methods with junit? if not could you provide the whole class

Comment: @AlexWien: Yes, i need to wriye Unittest case for the method getGridFilters

Comment: package com.jpmc.cb.creos.util.grid;
import java.io.IOException;
public class GridHelper {
  public static List<GridFilter> getGridFilters(String jsonFilters) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
  {
 List<GridFilter> filters = new ArrayList<GridFilter>();
 GridFilter filter[] = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFilters,
     GridFilter[].class);
 for (int i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
    filters.add(filter[i]);
   }
   return filters;}
}

Comment: Please edit the question to include this. You may have noticed you can't do multi-line code or blockquotes in comments...

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas for what to test. Write test methods for (at least) the following cases:

- a well formed json with 2 filters should return a list with two filters with matching values
- a well formed json with no filters should return an empty list
- a malformed json should raise a JsonParseException
- other bad data to raise the other exception types

How to write the test cases? Not clear what you're asking. But here's an example:

```
@Test
public void empty_json_gives_empty_list() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(Collections.emptyList(), GridHelper.getGridFilters("[]"));
}
```

Comment: underscores in methods names? which style checker does not cry?

Comment: Mine doesn't (sonar). Different rules apply to real code and unit tests. Unit test cases should have descriptive names, which tend to be long, and snake_case makes them easier to read. Non-test code should use camelCase of course

Comment: emptyJsonGivesEmptyList() I only see a limit of camelCase in unit test cases that need digits at end: testVersion9_4() is indeed more descriptive than  testVersion9dot4()

Comment: @janos: your idea "collections.emptylist()" works for me. Thank you so much

Comment: @janos: Yeah, I don't know what to use for malformed to raise an exception

Comment: If you don't know how to trigger such error, can't you remove the `throws` clause?